# How can I change the color of my text when I first added the color to the container?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I was trying to change the color of my text after I changed the color of the container. I did this but I did this but I got an error as below:

"No named parameter with the name 'color'.
`style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),color: Colors.white),`"
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
      Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            //width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.grey[900],
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  //height: 150,
                  // width: 150,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                const Text(
                  "Escorts",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 32,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Angenturen & Clubs",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 32,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Inserieren",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 32,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Werben",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 32,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Blog",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 32,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Kontakt",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                const Icon(
                  Icons.attach_money,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                const Icon(
                  Icons.chat,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                const Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                const Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 32,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.grey[900],
     child: Row(
        children: const [
          SizedBox(
            width: 40,
          ),
          Text("Inserieren",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),color: Colors.white),
         
        ],
      ),
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            SizedBox(
              width: 40.0,
            ),          
            Text("Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et\n quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. \n Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.\n Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,\n consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.\n Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?\n Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur,\n vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?",
          maxLines: 20,  style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.amber,),)
          ],
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: Row(
          children: const [
            SizedBox(
              width: 30.0,
            ),
            Text("tekst")
          ],
        ),
      )
   
       ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[image: imag2]

Comment: could you please include you code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling `color` out of `textStyle`, try this:

```
Text('Inseieren', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),)
```

For your long text you can wrap it with `Expanded` widget, like this:

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const [
              SizedBox(
                width: 40.0,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et\n quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. \n Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.\n Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,\n consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.\n Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?\n Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur,\n vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?",
                  maxLines: 20,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: May I ask you something else? I'm trying to add a text paragraph in flutter but the text is shows only in one line and it overflows screen. How can I fix this? @eamirho3ein

Comment: @Amarildo, yes of course.